# OSX Vim :set laststatus=2 shows only the filename -- but I want to see everything that Ctrl-g provides

Tags: macos, vim

Like the title says -- and my google fu fails me as `:set laststatus=2` shows only the filename, I'd like to see everything cntrl-g provides.

example:

```
<relative filename> line 28 of 285 --9%-- col 5
```

Pretty sure I remember pulling this off with a basic :set command a decade ago, any idea what's going on?  Again, all I'm seeing with `:set laststatus=2` is the filename.

bar@baz:~/foo$ vim --version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 23 2012 13:50:52)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
-conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
-mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs 
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses
```

Comment: Just tried `:set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P` (an example I saw in `:h status`) .. does nothing.  Status bar stays empty.  I'll try other things but I'm pretty certain that there's something else going on here, preventing it from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:set ruler
```

gives you at least some of the information you want. If you want more, read `:help 'statusline'`.

Comment: :set ruler satisfies it!

Answer (score 5):

the option `laststatus` has nothing to do with "what would be displayed on my status bar". It controls, when/how to display the status-bar.

- `0` (never)
- `1` only if you have more than 2 windows, the status bar shows
- `2` always

if you want to control **what** would be shown on your status bar, you should check another option: `statusline`

```
:h statusline
```

will give you detailed information. you can DIY a lot.

To your question, personally I have this statusline:

https://github.com/sk1418/myConf/blob/master/common/.vimrc#L506

it shows for example:

```
~/.vimrc [VIM:unix:utf-8:] [ASCII:61] [row:513/715 71% col:18]
```

Comment: ~/.vimrc is executable?  Mine isn't.  Just tried your settings -- the github settings; and it doesn't display anything on my status line.  I also just tried this: (ripped from :h statusline) `:set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P`, which also displays nothing.

Comment: @Squeaky 1) vimrc doesn't need to be `x` 2) cp my statusline or write your own in your vimrc, and you may also want to put `set laststatus=2` there. if you tested with mine, note that I have 4 lines codes about the statusline.

Comment: hah, right, I was misreading your example as input and not output.  Anyway, so yes, I did see the 4 lines.  I can't get it to work on 2 different systems actually.  It simply does nothing on one, and doesn't change the existing status line on the other system.

Comment: Kent, thanks, I didn't :set laststatus after trying your settings.  Have an upvote!